# Formatting a table output to a file :: numpy python

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, format

Usually I save a numpy array to a file in python using the command

```
np.savetxt("output.dat",table1)
```

But the output generated is not very nice. I want to assign a particular number of characters to each column irrespective of the number of digits in the entry and right justify them. For example, if I assign 5 characters to each column my output file should look like

```
   3.4   2.5   1.3
  24.5  34.2   4.5
 34.56   0.5  0.55
```

and so on. Is there is a simple way to do this? Also I don't want to do it by writing a `for` loop over the array as they are very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.savetxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) takes a format argument. You can use that to format the output how ever you want.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> table = np.array([[3.4, 2.5, 1.3], [24.5, 34.2, 4.5], [34.56, 0.5, 0.55]])
>>> np.savetxt('output.dat', table, '%6.2f')
```

results in:

```
  3.40   2.50   1.30
 24.50  34.20   4.50
 34.56   0.50   0.55
```

Comment: is it possible to mention the number of characters to be left blank between columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is that you want, but the delimiter parameter(the fourth one) can probably help.